# Deleting own answer (bug?)

Tags: bug, specific-answer, vote-to-delete

I just tried to delete an answer I'd posted on SO (it wasn't very good). Surprisingly I needed to delete it three times before the system would delete it even though I was logged in. Prior to today, if it was my answer, I only need to click the delete button once.

I clicked delete and a number 1 appeared against the word 'delete'. I then had to delete it again (number 2 appeared) and then on the (third) final time was it deleted.

Is this new or a bug?

Comment: I've re-opened this. To be clear - ***users can post bugs on the meta site attached to their favorite site*** - we patrol meta sites, we have for _years_, this is nothing really new. If something is so impacting that it needs to go to MSE, we'll send it there, just like we would have over the last few years. This _isn't_ new guidance, we've been giving it for years on all of our child meta sites, Stack Overflow is now _no_ different in that aspect than any other site.

Comment: I saw this bug the other day, I think this is new (and a bug)!

Comment: I'm seeing this bug as well in my own answer. I tried to delete it (4 times) and it currently says -1 more votes are needed to delete. Bizarre: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9576498/691569